# Laravel универсальный select запрос в бд

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

не могу найти материалов, чтобы реализовать с помощью Laravel Eloquent какой-то плюс минус универсальный запрос выборки из базы данных.
Чтобы он одинаково хорошо работал и с limit и без него, и с order by и без него, с условием и без и т.д.
В обычном php это реализовывалось при помощи подачи в функцию массивов и переменных и в зависимости от них при помощи конкатенации получался составной запрос, а как делать что-то подобное в Laravel? Ведь, в ларе это не просто string строка, которую можно сунуть в query запрос и т.д., здесь же обращение к методам класса идет. Не понимаю, как это реализовать.
Спасибо за внимание=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
function getAllRecords($limit=false, $offset=false, $order=false)
{
    $records = Record::whereNotNull('title')
        ->when($limit, function ($query, $limit) {
            return $query->limit($limit);
        })
        ->when($offset, function ($query, $offset) {
            return $query->offset($offset);
        })
        ->when($order, function ($query, $order) {
            return $query->orderBy($order);
        })
        ->get();

    return $records;
}
```

А можно и так:

```
function getAllRecords($limit=false, $offset=false, $order=false)
{
    $records = Record::whereNotNull('title');
    if ( !empty($limit) && !empty($offset) ) {
        $records = $records->limit($limit)->offset($offset);
    }
    if ( !empty($order) ) {
        $records = $records->orderBy($order);
    }
    $records = $records->get();
    return $records;
}
```

Принцип тут тот же, только вместо строки собирается объект.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к InDevX:

Думаю лучше подобные методы вешать на скопы модели

```
/**
* @param Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
* @param int|null $limit
* @param int|null $offset
* @param string|null $order колонка по которой будет производится сортировка
*
* @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
*/
public function scopeGetAllRecords(
    Builder $builder,
    ?int $limit = null,
    ?int $offset,
    ?string $order = null
): Collection {
    return $builder->whereNotNull('title')
        ->when($limit, function(Builder $subBuilder, int $limit) {
            return $subBuilder->limit($limit);
        })->when($offset, function(Builder $subBuilder, int $offset) {
            return $subBuilder->offset($offset);
        })->when($order, function(Builder $subBuilder, int $order) {
            return $subBuilder->reorder($order);
        })->get();
}
```

Теперь когда вы вызываете какую либо модель вы можете сразу обратится к скопе

```
Model::getAllRecords($limit, $offset, $order);
```

Либо добавить какое то условие если оно вдруг понадобиться

```
Model::where('active', true)->getAllRecords($limit, $offset, $order);
```

Comment: order пофиксить надо

Comment: А еще круче не заканчивать скоп. А дальше вернуть Builder и позволить дальше строить запрос. При этом используя все скопы модели дальше. Active Record все же :)

Comment: @MikielD. относительно согласен, но если эти запросы постоянно повторяются и всегда с гетом то в целом можно и скопу начать с get как я сделал и уже понятно что это возвращающий скоп, и дальнейшее действие уже с коллекцией или моделью